# Why segmentation fault in case 2 of this program for matrix multiplication (using dynamic memory allocation) and not for matrix addition (case 1)?

Tags: c, matrix

I wrote this code, using dynamic memory allocation for different operations on matrix. In this program when I am calling the `inputmatrix(a,r,c)` in the switch case 2 for matrix multiplication then, the compiler is showing me segmentation fault.

code -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int** inputmatrix(int **a,int r, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    a = (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("\n Input the Elements of the Matrix :");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int** add(int **a, int **b, int r, int c)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int** multiplication(int** a, int **b, int r1, int c1, int c2)
{
    int **c,i,j,k;
    c = (int**)malloc(r1*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<c2; i++)
    {
        c[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for(k=0; k<c1; k++)
            {
                c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int **a, **b,r1,c1,r2,c2, i,j,ch;
    int **c;
    printf("\n enter your choice : \n1.Addition \n2.Multiplication \n3.Saddle Point \n4. Magic Square \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: printf("\n enter the oder of matrix A :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
                printf("\n enter the oder of matrix B :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
                if(r1==r2 && c1==c2)
                {
                    a = inputmatrix(a,r1,c1);
                    b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                    a = add(a,b,r1,c1);
                    printf("\n the result of the addition of matrices is :");
                    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(j=0;j<c1; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n these matrices can't be added ");
                }
                break;
        case 2 : printf("\n enter the oder of matrix A :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);

                printf("\n Enter the Order of Matrix B :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r2,c2);
                a = inputmatrix(a,r1,c1);
                b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                if(c1 == r2)
                {


                    c = multiplication(a, b, r1, c1, r2);
                    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n Sorry, These Matrices Can't be Multiplied ");
                }
                break;
        default : printf("\n Sorry, This is a Wrong Choice ");
            }
    return 0;
}
```

The main problem is with this segment -

```
case 2 : printf("\n enter the oder of matrix A :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);

                printf("\n Enter the Order of Matrix B :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r2,c2);
                a = inputmatrix(a,r1,c1);
                b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                if(c1 == r2)
                {
                    c = multiplication(a, b, r1, c1, r2);
                    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here when I made this `inputmatrix()` function to be called outside the switch of case 2 then, there is no segmentation fault.

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. C is not C++.

Comment: There are multiple errors. Reommend to read again about pointers and arrays in C. For instance: you are instantly overwriting `a` and `c` in your functions, use wrong types for `malloc`ed sizes, etc. Compiler warnings are there for a reason. Enable them and pay heed to them!

Comment: Ex: `scanf("%d%d",&r2,c2);` ? um.. see something different between those args ?

Comment: ya, i got this silly mistake done by me, Olaf i'm interested in knowing that what made you to write "C is not C++"??

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay: the cast is necessary if you are misguided enough to use `malloc()` in C++.  In C, it is not necessary — and there are those who argue that the cast can lead to problems.

Comment: The whole of inputmatrix is terribly broken. sizeof(int) and sizeof(*int) are not the same thing, for example. Why allocate a to have r elements, and then iterate over c elements. etc.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay - On behalf of Olaf, I'm mentioning the reason `why C is not C++`.  Check this link to know why ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: `a = (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }` --> `a = (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(c*sizeof(int));
    }`